# Plotly go.Choropleth not rendering correctly on front-end

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I'm trying to make a web dashboard with plotly graph objects (go).

I’m having a problem with a go.Choropleth. There’s something wrong when I’m trying to render it on the html page.

When I make the mapbox to simply show it in a jupyter notebook, it works fine. This is the code:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=regions,
                                    locations=full_latest_grouped2['Region'],
                                    featureidkey="properties.NOME_REG",
                                    z=full_latest_grouped2['Confirmed'], 
                                    colorscale='matter', 
                                    zmin=0, zmax=max(full_latest_grouped2['Confirmed']),
                                    marker_opacity=0.8, marker_line_width=0.1))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=4, mapbox_center = {"lat": 41.8719, "lon": 12.5674})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.update_layout(title='Confirmed Cases by Region')
fig.show()
```

But in the app the object does not render properly https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN6JM.jpg. I think I’m doing something wrong in the backend process.

In the backend, I’m making a list of figures that will then be rendered in the frontend.

This is the example of the choropleth mapbox (which is the first in my list):

```
figures.append(dict(data=graph_one, layout=layout_one))
```

where

```
graph_one = []

graph_one.append(
            go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(
            geojson=regions,
            locations=full_latest_grouped2['Region'],
            featureidkey="properties.NOME_REG",
            z=full_latest_grouped2['Confirmed'],
            colorscale='matter',
            zmin=0,
            zmax=max(full_latest_grouped2['Confirmed']),
            marker_opacity=0.8, marker_line_width=0.1)))

layout_one = dict(title = "Confirmed Cases by Region",
    mapbox_style = "carto-positron",
    mapbox_zoom = 4, mapbox_center = dict(lat = 41.8719, lon = 12.5674),
    margin = dict(r = 0, t = 30, l = 0, b = 0))
```

I’m then using the JSON encoder to convert the plotly figures to JSON for the javascript in my html.

```
figuresJSON = json.dumps(figures, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
```

I think I’m doing something wrong when I’m making the graph_one and layout_one objects. It might be because the Choropleth is wrapped around a Figure object?

I have go.Bar objects in my list of figures, and they render fine.

This is an example of a go.Scatter:

```
graph_two = []

graph_two.append(
      go.Bar(
      x = df.country.tolist(),
      y = df.hectaresarablelandperperson.tolist(),
      )
    )

layout_two = dict(title = 'Hectares Arable Land per Person in 2015',
                xaxis = dict(title = 'Country',),
                yaxis = dict(title = 'Hectares per person'),
                )
```

Comment: It's my understanding that 'plotly' is a local environment where the library is installed and the visualization is For a web-based visualization, use 'Dash' [Dash User Guide](https://dash.plotly.com/)

Comment: You can create a fig=figure(...) in the backend, open a html_stream=StringIO (or BytesIO) stream, call fig.write_html(html_stream). Then you decode the stream and send the results to your frontend. Am on mobile so no Code unfortunately.

Comment: @r-beginners not necessary. Just send the figure as a html string.

Comment: Or you need to find the correct JavaScript and insert that into your page. To do that, I’d also call fig.write_html(...) and search for all of the <script> tags.

Comment: 'Plotly' means a framework for creating HTML based on 'plotly'. That was my lack of understanding.

Comment: @AlexNe Thank you for your help, Alex! How can I decode the html string in the frontend? (sorry, I'm a rookie)

Comment: Either you build your whole html page on the backend or google „JavaScript Set inner html“ but then you need some way of communication between your frontend and backend. I’d suggest you provide a REST Endpoint on your backend and query it with Ajax. But now we’re getting into deep waters